# Dicom Images non square

Tags: c#, rows, dicom, square

I'm working with a set of DICOM images that are 512(columns) X 384(rows)

Is there a tool that would make the images 512X512? That is, filling the rows in this case to make it 512.

I've researched VTK with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: You can already do this in C# see [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084387/how-resize-image-without-losing-quality) but in your case you are _not_ maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I should have clarified these are Dicom Images..

Comment: Right, then you are looking for an SDK that can directly manipulate the PixelData in the dicom file and do the image resize.

Comment: If you make changes to image resolution, please update the appropriate DICOM tag (e.g. pixel spacing related tag such as Imager Pixel Spacing (0018,1164) to reflect the change.

Answer (score 2):

Argh, you was almost there! In fact, **VTK** is not the proper tool for that. **ITK** is.
To be precise, VTK is for 3D visualization (that is, rendering of 3D objects), while ITK is specifically concerned for image processing.

So, using ITK, you could use a *padding filter*, here's a complete example from the official wiki, ready to be compiled and executed: http://public.kitware.com/pub/itk/Examples/src/Filtering/ImageGrid/PadAnImageWithAConstant/Documentation.html.

But, if you want to do the things in an easier way, I suggest MATLAB (ITK could be difficult to configure). In this case, this post could help: [Padding an image in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597187/padding-an-image-in-matlab).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Anything in C#?

Comment: @Matimont: Well, I worked using ITK in C++ only. But there is SimpleITK, that is a wrapper (but maybe I've just misused this term, sorry) of ITK for C#. However, I don't know if the padding filter is implemented there (as the name suggests, SimpleITK should have less functionality than the "standard" library).

Comment: Right, I tried SimpleITK and does not include padding.
Do you know of another alternative? I may end up modifying the pixel data and adding "0" to pad the image

Comment: Unfortunately not...I linked the solutions I know; plus, I'm not a C# expert. I'm sorry...